# Scaling independent poly selections by the center of each selection

Tags: transforms, selection-tools

[image: Non contiguous Selections]

I would like to scale each of these cylinder shaped selections down by say 5% (i.e. making hole smaller). Is there anyway to do that with a single selection, or do I need to do each one sperately?

Related, is there a way to enter a numerical scale value like 5%?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>.</kbd>, then <kbd>`I`</kbd>, or use the menu on top of the viewport to switch *"Transform Pivot Point"* to *"Individual Origins"*:

[image]

As for your additional question, yes, you can press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>↩ Enter</kbd>, or you can scale by any amount and then expand the operator popup by clicking on it or pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> - there you will be able to adjust the operator values.

Comment: Fantastic, easy. Thanks!